# Ideas for speeding up installing dependencies

Tags: c++, continuous-integration, travis-ci, build-dependencies

I have a project that depends on many external libraries like GLFW3, GLEW, GLM, FreeType2, zlib etc. It would be best to store/share installed dependencies between jobs so it wouldn't have to download/install them all the time which takes about half of the time. I can see couple ideas how to handle it:

a) for each job for each build download dependencies and install them

b) put dependencies (sources) inside my repo and have little speedup becouse i will no longer have to download them from outside servers (still have to compile and install them)

c) compile them by hand, put on some server and just download right package for each build

---

a) it leaves least work for me to update dependencies for building and testing, allows to use newest versions to build my project but it takes most time (both compiling and downloading)

b) bloats repository with extra code (not mine), gives little speedup (downloading is not that slow usually), adds manual work to update dependencies, i guess worse then a)

c) fastest but requires most work from me to constantly keep built dependencies up to date and upload them on fast server (also diffrent per each build task (compiler etc)), allows for fastest builds (just download & copy/install).

So, how are you managing your external dependencies and keep them up to date for your travis builds?

Note that i use free version of Travis and kinda need sudo for updating cmake, gcc etc. and installing dependencies... Could somehow trick CMake to use local versions of dependencies instead of /usr/... but this somehow bloats CMake which i believe should be very simple and clear.

Comment: You should try to avoid asking two questions in one topic. Maybe it would be a good idea to create another for your second question.

Comment: No idea about the time limits. As for speeding things up, I would try to cache as many of the dependencies as possible: http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/caching/

Comment: Note that caching works with containers or on paid versions, and i need sudo to install dependencies and to update-alternatives for gcc (gcc must link to gcc5, not this old default version). So built-in caching doesn't really help me.

Answer (score 0):

Let's call the entire set of dependencies your build requires at some point in time the dependency "lineup".

I'd separate **the use of (a certain version of) the lineup** in your builds from the task of **updating the lineup version** (when a new version of a dependency is needed) - mixing them unnecessarily complicates the picture IMHO (I'm assuming that many of your builds would use the same dependency lineup version).

Let's look at the **use of the lineup** first.

From your description the **installation** of the (already built) dependencies is common to all 3 options and executed at every build, so let's put that aside for now.

The difference between your approaches remains only in **how you obtain** the built dependencies:

- **a** - download them from outside servers - at every build
- **b** - build them from repo sources - at every build
- **c** - download them from a local fast server - at every build

It seems **a** and **c** are fundamentally the same except **c** would be faster due to local access. Most likely **b** would be the slowest.

So it looks like **c** is the winner from the build speed prospective in this context.

Now the question would be if/how you can get your built dependencies lineup on the local server faster for the **c** approach. I see 2 options (unsure if they're both possible in your context):

1. download dependencies already built (as you would in your **a**
   approach) from outside servers (effectively just caching them on the
   local servers)
2. building dependencies locally from source, except you don't have to neither place those sources in the same repo as your project nor build them for every project build (as in your **b** approach) - you only need to do this when you **update your lineup** (and only for new versions of the respective dependencies).

You could also look into mixing of the 2 options: some dependencies using option **1**, others using option **2**, as you see fit.

Now, if you're using VM (or docker or similar) images for your build machines and you have control over such images it *might* be possible to significantly speedup your builds by customizing these VM images - have the dependency lineup installed on them, making them immediately available to any build on a machine running such customized image.

Finally, when time comes to **update your dependency lineup** (which, BTW, should be present in your **a** and **b** approaches, too, not only in the **c** one) you'd have to just download the new dependencies versions, build them if needed, store the built dependencies on the local fast server and, if the customized VM image solution works for you, update/re-create the customized VM image with the installation of the new dependency lineup.

Comment: I'm not sure if you saw that I use Travis-CI (free version) so i have no control over VM images whatsoever. I can't even use some repos in new container-based mode, only in legacy mode which is slower. Also you made a mistake - my 'a' is closer to 'b' as i have to build all libraries in 'a' by hand too, just don't download them at once with my repo, but each dependency is downloaded from diffrent server which probably is slower than github server (but putting dependencies on my repo bloats it).

Comment: OK, no custom VM optimisation. Since a) involves building dependencies as well then things are really simple: c) remains the winner, with option 2) for building the dependencies before storing them on the local fast server from where you install them at every build.

Comment: Yes, but: 1. building dependencies locally takes some time and it's boring. I'd have to manually build newer versions couple times per month or so. 2. Having compiling project on many compilers (diff versions) etc. i'd have to prepare package for each build job and download diffrent version then. It takes a lot of time. Best solution would be to be able to build dependencies once a month on Travis-CI and other builds would use cached versions, but this is impossible on free account for now :/